# Why is my Google maps marker width restricted?

Tags: html, css

https://sinlimo.com/contact.php

I can't seem to adjust the size of the marker containing the text. I tried forcing the width and enabling nowrap but to no avail.

```
        ,boxStyle: {
            opacity: 0.75
            ,width: "280px"
            ,whiteSpace: "nowrap"
        }
```

Comment: Remove `max-width: 100%` from `.infoBox` class,  then adjust the `width` setting.

Answer (score 0):

please give below css and check

```
.infoBox {
    width: 270px!Important;
  max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: Same outcome unfortunately.